# ApplicationCommands.Delete.Execute()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to execute a delete command like this:

```
ApplicationCommands.Delete.Execute(Keyboard.FocusedElement, Keyboard.FocusedElement);
```

But:

```
ApplicationCommands.Delete.CanExecute(Keyboard.FocusedElement, Keyboard.FocusedElement)
```

is false, so it's not executed.

How can I change it to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to set up [`CommandBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding)s that specify what happens when the Execute and CanExecute functions are called.

Here's an example:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete"
                        Executed="DeleteCommandHandler"
                        CanExecute="DeleteCanExecuteHandler" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <StackPanel Name="MainStackPanel">
        <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" 
                Content="Delete File" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

That example comes from the [CommandBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding) documentation (slightly modified).